# Which vegan WWE athletes were mentioned in 'The Plant-Based Athlete'?

Tags: veganism, sports

I returned my copy of *The Plant Based Athlete* by Matt Frazier and Robert Cheeke, but I recall it mentioned a handful of plant-based WWE superstars.

Who were they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rechecked out the book, and they were:

- [Austin Aries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austin_Aries) (Daniel Solwold, Jr.)
- Daniel Bryan (Brian Danielson)
- CM Punk (Phillip Brooks)
- Ryback (Ryan Allen Reeves)
- Allie (Laura Dennis)